# SelectableRegion setState selection lost

Tags: flutter, flutter-state, flutter-text

In the following example I have a SelectableRegion containing a list of text widgets and I call setState() every second. If I remove 'SelectionContainer.disabled' in 'TextWidget' then the selection state survives setState, otherwise it loses the text selection. Can you please why this issue happens and how to properly fix it?

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:lets_hang/locations/map_text_selection.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

class SelectionTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const SelectionTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SelectionTest> createState() => _SelectionTestState();
}

class _SelectionTestState extends State<SelectionTest> {
  final _selectableRegionFocusNode = FocusNode();
  late final Timer _timer;
  var count = 1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 1500), (timer) {
      count++;
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    _selectableRegionFocusNode.dispose();
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SelectableRegion(
      selectionControls: MapTextSelectionControls(),
      focusNode: _selectableRegionFocusNode,
      child: Container(
        width: 200,
        height: 300,
        color: Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt())
            .withOpacity(1.0),
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => TextWidget(key: ValueKey(index)),
          itemCount: count,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final textSpans = <InlineSpan>[
      const TextSpan(text: 'Hey 123 456 789'),
      WidgetSpan(
        child: SelectionContainer.disabled(
          child: Text(
            '-> No issue if I remove SelectionContainer.disabled <-',
            maxLines: 1,
            style: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .bodyMedium!
                .copyWith(color: Colors.transparent),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ];

    return Text.rich(TextSpan(children: textSpans));
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a code example

Comment: could you provide a mvp showing only the problem you have where i can take the code to test it out? Fixing it with the provided code is really specific and difficult. you could also put the code in a github repo so that can i take a look

Comment: @MarcelDz I have provided a completely distilled full example that you can copy paste.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution , that is you will take the chat bubble and put it in a `stateless` or `statefull` **class** . then call it in your current class and before it add `const` .

Answer (score 0):

Without some more code is really difficult to know, but assuming that what you can try to wrap with a StatefulBuilder the widget that throws the setState and isolate it with it.

Comment: I added code to show the difficulty of insulating it from setState

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Hamed I edited the answer to make it clearer and easier